# How to insert big forward slash to label matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I would like to know how to insert a big forward slash symbol in labeling matplotlib axes.

A trick that should work in normal latex environment didn't work even after importing the amsmath package using the plt.rcParams.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
# Doesn't display properly!
plt.xlabel(r'$\left. \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right.$')
```

I got the following error message:

```
ValueError: 
\left. \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right.
                                    ^
Expected "\right" (at char 40), (line:1, col:41)
```

Comment: Removing the first 2 lines (excluding the import) and using `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` works for me. This requires an external working version of LaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and I found a solution that works without `usetex=True`. Matplotlib accepts `/` in combination with `\left`, so you can do something like this:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \left/ \int_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right. $')
```

Result:

[image: Matplotlib formula with large slash]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the forward slash, but the `\middle` command. I've tried to scale up the `/` in the middle with no success. However, you can make it more visible by giving it some more space:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} $ / $\int_c^d \frac{x}{y} $')
```

I removed the `\left` and `\right` all together, because I didn't see any difference using it. Additionally, `\limits` does not seem to work with the standard latex engine, and I scrapped those too.

It currently looks like:

[image: Equation using normal engine]

If this is not acceptable, I suggest following the recommendation from DavidG in comments which makes your original command work. It looks like:

[image: Equation using LaTeX]